# How to encrypt with unknown initialization vector?

Tags: apex, crypto

How can I generate an AES encrypted token with a shared key and using the following AES cipher attributes in apex?

- Rijndael cipher
- Electronic Code Book mode (ECB) / Galois Counter Mode (GCM)
- No built in padding (such as PKCS)

  - This one is a bit of a concern to me given that Salesforce includes in its [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_classes_restful_crypto.htm#apex_System_Crypto_encrypt), "They use cipher block chaining (CBC) and PKCS7 padding."
- Resultant encrypted buffer should be manually padded with spaces to achieve the total length a multiple of 32. That is: length(encrypted padded string) mod 32 = 0

The API docs provides the following sample values:

- Key: `4FCD5FAE2AC493C0F8CE8E1E6105D194`
- Raw Token: `iframe=true;customer.firstName=John;customer.lastName=Smith;header.accountNumber=6759370;header.authToken1=12345;header.paymentTypeCode=UTILITY;header.amount=123.45`
- Encrypted Token: `4BA596898953113C3D8AAF6BC30F9FE8EB04C699FEE510707725146937227946D8C1AD49500D7AAE72EE2D2CEA4FA1663703F00B730DACB7DB5F4FFB07DE716C7E339FFA25FBE7F61237EC11FCC53989ADAC97B10C7EFB3DC5CBBA526CD43CD3D84E10BD687329F627A52015960ABF1D5546F53447B2B3D9D6734F2FB6E3538D97F8332953B930A5953DAB3FEC2C8C9A423F63D9D6B51CD72F7E3AF644973F15A4BB7D901ACA6B96558C80C5271EF95A1CE53A43557C295F3D6FC9678EE0557F`

My assumption is that I need to provide the initialization vector in [`Crypto.encrypt(algorithmName, privateKey, initializationVector, clearText)`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_classes_restful_crypto.htm#apex_System_Crypto_encrypt), but how do I do that with the provided key?

Comment: OOTB with Crypto class, you can't do it in ECB/GCM without padding regardless of whether you use IV or not. The only mode supported is CBC with padding as the docs clearly state. You'd have to use one of the 3rd party crypto libraries and then integrate with SF. One option is [Functions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/functions/overview).

Answer (score 0):

The AES implementations are limited. If you're trying to just deal with what Apex can do, you can use `Crypto.encryptWithManagedIv`, then you can decrypt with `Crypto.decryptWithManagedIv`, as follows:

```
String clearText = 'iframe=true;customer.firstName=John;customer.lastName=Smith;header.accountNumber=6759370;header.authToken1=12345;header.paymentTypeCode=UTILITY;header.amount=123.45';
Blob key = EncodingUtil.convertFromHex('4FCD5FAE2AC493C0F8CE8E1E6105D194');

// To encrypt:
Blob clearBlob = Blob.valueOf(clearText);
Blob encryptedBlob = Crypto.encryptWithManagedIV('AES128', key, clearBlob);
// Final hex-encoded output
String encryptedText = EncodingUtil.convertToHex(encryptedBlob);

// To decrypt:
Blob encryptedData = EncodingUtil.convertFromHex(encryptedText);
Blob decryptedBlob = Crypto.decryptWithManagedIV('AES128', key, encryptedData);
// Final original clear text
String decryptedText = decryptedBlob.toString();
```

Otherwise, the far end would need to separately give you its IV, which must have been used in the original calculation. Just as a trial, I did try to use a blank IV:

```
Blob encrypted = EncodingUtil.convertFromHex('4BA596898953113C3D8AAF6BC30F9FE8EB04C699FEE510707725146937227946D8C1AD49500D7AAE72EE2D2CEA4FA1663703F00B730DACB7DB5F4FFB07DE716C7E339FFA25FBE7F61237EC11FCC53989ADAC97B10C7EFB3DC5CBBA526CD43CD3D84E10BD687329F627A52015960ABF1D5546F53447B2B3D9D6734F2FB6E3538D97F8332953B930A5953DAB3FEC2C8C9A423F63D9D6B51CD72F7E3AF644973F15A4BB7D901ACA6B96558C80C5271EF95A1CE53A43557C295F3D6FC9678EE0557F');
Blob key = EncodingUtil.convertFromHex('4FCD5FAE2AC493C0F8CE8E1E6105D194');
Blob iv = EncodingUtil.convertFromHex('0'.repeat(32));
Blob decryptedBlob = Crypto.decrypt('AES128', key, iv, encrypted);
String decryptedText = decryptedBlob.toString();
```

But this also failed. You'll need the IV, or you'll need to use an implementation that is Apex compatible.